# Finding F(10) and a relation between double derivative and function is given

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem :

If $f''(x)=-f(x),$ where f(x) is a continuous double differentiable function and $g(x) =f'(x) $ If F(x) =(f$(\frac{x}{2}))^2+(g(\frac{x}{2}))^2$ and F(5)=5, then find F(10)

Attempt :

If $g(x) =f'(x) \Rightarrow g'(x) = f''(x) = -f(x) $

I am getting no clue how to proceed further.... please make this concept clear how to solve such problems, Thanks...

Comment: What happens if you apply the chain rule to differentiate $F(x)$ in terms of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: We have a function for which its second derivative is its negative -- sound like anything you've heard off?  Particularly a function for which the _first_ derivative has an important Identity relating the _square_ of that function to the _square_ of the function which happens to be its derivative?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Evaluate $F'(x) =$ using the chain rule..

Comment: F'(x) = 2f'(\frac{x}{2}).f(\frac{x}{2})+2g'(\frac{x}{2})g(\frac{x}{2}) $  = 2f'(\frac{x}{2}).f(\frac{x}{2})-2f(\frac{x}{2}).f'(\frac{x}{2})$ = 0  Is it correct please help further.. how to proceed.... thanks

Comment: @sultan Great. And if the derivate of a function is 0 everywhere, what can you say about the function?

Comment: Its a constant function therefore F(5)=F(10) =5 I think I got it.. Thanks..